# WPF: How to created a routed event for content changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, eventtrigger, routed-events

I have a frame. I switch pages with this line:

```
FrameName.Content = new PageName();
```

I want a storyboard to begin when the page has changed, and I want to do it in XAML, and not in code-behind. I have tried the following code:

```
<Frame.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentChanged">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboardName}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</Frame.Triggers>
```

After searching a bit I realized there is no built-in routed event of that nature. The first answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5421e988-f729-4154-b1ab-e17e1b8b70d4/labelcontent-changed-event?forum=wpf) suggests that

> The most dynamic approach is to simply derive your own <s>label</s> control that provides a ContentChanged event.

I have tried to implement the code in this answer:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ContentChangedTest
{
    class MyFrame : Frame
    {
        public event DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler ContentChanged;

        static MyFrame()
        {
            ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyFrame), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnContentChanged)));
        }

        private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyFrame frame = dp as MyFrame;

            if (frame.ContentChanged != null)
            {
                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args = new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(ContentProperty, e.OldValue, e.NewValue);
                frame.ContentChanged(frame, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML I use it look like this:

```
<local:MyFrame ContentChanged="MyFrame_ContentChanged" />
```

The problem is that eventually I need to create an event handler `MyFrame_ContentChanged` in the code-behind. Is there a way to do this in pure XAML? For example - can I convert the `ContentChanged` dependency property to some sort of routed event?

Comment: I am very new to WPF, so it is more than likely that this is a stupid question. However, I would be grateful for a serious answer.

Comment: In order to use it in `EventTrigger` you need to use a `RoutedEvent`. Routed events are defined similarly to dependency properties. A good starting point for you would be this tutorial: [How to: Create a Custom Routed Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @Grx70,  Thanks. Could you please demonstrate how it works and how can I integrate that with the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use events with `EventTriggers` they should be routed events. Routed events are defined in a way similar to dependency properties. Here's a quick tutorial on how to get started: [How to: Create a Custom Routed Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288(v=vs.100).aspx).

Here's an example of a class deriving from `ContentControl` which defines a `ContentChanged` event:

```
public class MyContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ContentChangedEvent 
        = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            "ContentChanged",
            RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler), 
            typeof(MyContentControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ContentChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ContentChangedEvent, this));
    }
}
```

I'm not yet sure why, but while testing this line worked inside a `Style`, but threw an exception while used in the control's triggers collection directly:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentChanged">...</EventTrigger>
```

In order to make it work in this situation I had to specify a fully qualified event path:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MyContentControl.ContentChanged">...</EventTrigger>
```