# WPF InvokeCommandAction with ContentControl Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a content control:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding PageViewModel}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ContentChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ContentControl>
```

I need to invoke MyCommand every time PageViewModel changes.

However the command is not getting triggered.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Could it be that you have wrong/no datacontext? Or the code-behind failing? Please share your code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this in the setter of the `PageViewModel` property:

```
private object pageViewModel;
public object PageViewModel
{
    get { return pageViewModel; }
    set
    {
        pageViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        MyCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

A `ContentControl` has no `ContentChanged` event. It has a protected `OnContentChanged` method that you could override if you create a custom `ControlControl` class though:

[WPF: How to created a routed event for content changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384389/wpf-how-to-created-a-routed-event-for-content-changed)

You can create a custom event that you raise in this method.

But the MVVM way of doing this would be to invoke the command in the view model when the `PageViewModel` property is set.